# Rounding up columns values to nearest 10, then showing the percent of each group that satisfy a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, rounding

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Credit Scores':[695 ,704, 718], 'Delinquent': [True, False, True]})
df.head()
```

*Beginner Working with pandas dataFrames*

So I have created a dataFrame which includes the Credit Score of borrowers at origination of a loan and whether or not the loan went delinquent. I am hoping to group the scores together by rounding them too near 10 (i.e. 'Credit Scores' : 700, 710, 720, etc.) then finding the percent of the scores in each group that went delinquent. A sample output might look like this.

```
  Credit Score  Delinquency Rate
0      700           .43
1      710           .45
2      720           .41
```

I'm not sure how to do this and would greatly appreciate some guidance. Thank you

### Update

I am experiencing another problem

```
#round and group credit scores by 10's
df['Credit Score'] = round(df['Credit Score'], -1)

# group by credit score and sum the bool values divided by the size of each group
to_rate = df.groupby(round(df['Credit Score'], -1))['Delinquency Rate']

df['Delinquency Rate'] = to_rate.transform(sum) / to_rate.transform('size')

df.sort_values('Credit Score')
```

So when I sorted and displayed the values I noticed that Credit Scores were being repeated. I didn't seem to have grouped them properly...

```
    Credit Score    Delinquency Rate
54       450                1.0
17       470                0.0
28       470                0.0
10       480                0.5
59       480                0.5
```

How should I fix this? also is there a way to display more than just on decimal places?

### Updated Output

I removed this piece of code to avoid normalizing but now it is not rounding the values.

```
df['Credit Score'] = round(df['Credit Score'], -1)
```

New Output *after removing line above*

```
df.sort_values('Credit Score')

    Credit Score    Delinquency Rate
54     447                 1.0
28     471                 0.0
17     474                 0.0
21     475                 0.5
10     476                 0.5
... ... ...
16     839                 0.0
28     839                 0.0
45     839                 0.0
65     839                 0.0
62     839                 0.0
```

Comment: You want to round to the nearest 10 wouldn't your output be 650, 740, 860?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
# new sample df
df = pd.DataFrame({'Credit Scores':[654 ,738, 863, 649, 650],
                   'Delinquent': [True, False, True, True, False]})

# use round with -1 to round to the nearest 10
df['Credit Scores'] = round(df['Credit Scores'], -1)

# group by credit score and get the mean
s = df.groupby('Credit Scores')['Delinquent'].mean()

s.reset_index().plot(kind='scatter', x='Credit Scores', y='Delinquent')


               Delinquent
Credit Scores            
650              0.666667
740              0.000000
860              1.000000
```

Comment: thank you very much. Very helpful. If I wanted to display it as 2 separate (each with there respective labels) columns how would I do that?

Comment: @bostitch use to_frame: `(g.sum() / g.size()).to_frame()`

Comment: can I replace the old delinquent column (containing boolean) with new Delinquent Column (contain percentages) so they are on the same df?

Comment: @bostitch you can but you will lose your groups so you would have to use `transform` see update

Comment: @bostitch by "see update" I just mean that  updated my answer with how to use `transform`

Comment: I updated my question so it is easier to follow, but I am experiencing another issue with the repeated credit scores. Which means my groups do not contain all the scores of the same value.

Comment: @bostitch It is being "repeated" because you are normalizing the credit score: `df['Credit Score'] = round(df['Credit Score'], -1)` remove that line if you want the output from my last example.

Comment: I removed that but now It is not rounding at all, ill put the output im getting above

Comment: @bostitch it is rounding it is just not assigned to anything. You really need to read my answer. It is all explained there.

Comment: @Yo_Chris I think `g.transform(sum) / g.transform('size')` is actually `g.transform('mean')` ;)

Comment: @Yo_Chris  oh so the values are not repeating, they are just showing up multiple times, but the percentage is still representative of all the values for each credit score? If that is the case is there a way to delete the repeated values but keep the percentage the same? maybe that's not necessary

Comment: @bostitch that is correct. It really sounds like you just want to do the first example: `df['Credit Scores'] = round(df['Credit Scores'], -1); new_df = df.groupby('Credit Scores')['Delinquent'].mean().to_frame()`

Comment: yeah but I am trying to plot the variable via scatter plot and with your initial answer I couldn't do it

Comment: reset the index `new_df.reset_index().plot(kind='scatter', x='Credit Scores', y='Delinquent')`

Comment: Ok that worked, thanks so much for your time. --- if I want to change and say round to the nearest 5, is that an easy change?

Comment: @bostitch round up to nearest 5: `df['Credit Scores'] = (df['Credit Scores']+5) // 5*5` round down to nearest 5: `df['Credit Scores'] = (df['Credit Scores']-5) // 5*5`

Comment: Thanks, I'll leave you alone now :)